# Roots of $P(P(x))$ where 5th degree (or higher) $P(x)$ has all its coefficients and roots in $\mathbb Z$

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic, contest-math

A polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n \geq 5$ with integer coefficients and
$n$ distinct integer roots is given. Find all integer roots of $P(P(x))$
given that $0$ is a root of $P(x)$.

This is an old Czech math olympiad problem (1998) that I cannot find a solution to. Any ideas?

Comment: Certainly there are those of the original polynomial. I have a hard time to imagine what others there could always be present so maybe those are all. But that's just a guess, not even an educated one.

Comment: Find all integer roots?!  By god, that's an easy rational roots theorem, and we don't even have to expand fully?  :D

Comment: @Simple Art Can you elaborate your remark because it looks very cryptic to me (and maybe for the OP as well ?)

Comment: @JeanMarie See below?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $p(p(x))=0$ then $p(x)=n$ where $n$ is a root of $p$. Thus we have 
$$n=x(x-n)q(x)$$ where $q(x)$ is the product of at least three integers.
Since $x|n-x+x$ we have $x|n-x$ and since $n-x|n-x+x$ we have $n-x|x$ thus $n-x=\pm x$ the plus sign must hold since otherwise $n=0$. And the equation becomes
$$2x=\pm x^2 q(x)$$
 or if $x\neq 0$, $$2=\pm xq(x)$$ where $q(x)$ is a product of at least three distinct integers. This is impossible. Thus we must have either $x=0$ or $n=0$, in the latter case we see that $p(x)=0$ so $x$ is a root of the original polynomial, this includes $x=0$.

Comment: @achillehui Thats very gracious, thanks, but I liked your solution also. I gave it an upvote.

Comment: Good [sportsmanship](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/sportsmanship)

Comment: @SimpleArt Well now I am two closer.

Answer (score 3):

Use the rational roots theorem to extract all rational roots (which includes integer roots).  If $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x^1$, then

$$P(P(x))=(a_n)^{n+1}x^{2n}+\dots+a_1x^1$$

Factor out $x$ and then apply the rational roots theorem.

Thus, all rational roots are of the form

$$r=\pm\frac pq$$

where $p$ are the factors of $a_1$ and $q$ are the factors of $(a_n)^{n-1}$

---

To extract the trivial ones,

$$P(r)=0\tag{given roots}$$

$$P(P(r))=P(0)=0\tag{also given}$$

So all the original roots are still roots.

Comment: This doesn't prove that the original roots are the *only* roots, so it doesn't answer the `find *all*` part of the question, which is the more interesting part.

Comment: @dxiv That is arguable.  Given any polynomial, this method is guaranteed to find all integer roots, but on the other hand, it does not do anything for the general case.  Indeed it doesn't prove the original roots are the only roots, but that is not needed to answer the question.  The other answers are quite wonderful too (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say $P(x) = Ax\prod\limits_{k=2}^n(x-a_k)$ where $a_k$ are distinct non-zero integers. It is clear if $P(P(x)) = 0$, then $P(x)$ either vanishes or equal to one of the $a_i$. We claim that the second case is impossible for any integer $x$.

Assume the contrary, let says $P(m)$ equal to some $a_k$, say $a_2$ for integer $m \ne 0$.

Since $a_2 = A m\prod\limits_{k=2}^n (m - a_k)$ and the RHS (excludes $A$) is a product of $n \ge 5$ distinct integers,

$$|a_2| \ge |\pm 1|^2|\pm 2|^2|\pm 3| = 12$$

Rewrite the RHS as $m (a_2 - m) A \times\prod_{k=3}^n (m-a_k)$, the part
after $A$ consists of a product of at least 3 distinct integers. this implies

$$\left|\prod_{k=3}^n (m-a_k)\right| \ge |\pm 1|^2|\pm 2| = 2$$

and leads to

$$|a_2| = |LHS| = |RHS| \ge 2|m(m-a_2)| \ge 2||a_2| - 1|$$

It is easy to see above equation doesn't have any solution when $|a_2| \ge 12$.
As a result, the second case is impossible. So the only integer roots of $P(P(x))$ are those of $P(x)$.